# YouTube Analytics API returning strange results

Tags: youtube-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-php-client, youtube-data-api

I'm having a hard time with getting data from YouTubeAnalytics. I have created a client and its authenticating ok (I use the same client instance for google analytics). YouTubeAnalytics is enabled in google developer console but I seem to get different responses when using the AJAX console they provide to the [PHP client](http://github.com/google/google-api-php-client). My tests are;

#### Getting info for my channel id ("channel==MINE") - returns no data

```
$analytics = new Google_Service_YouTubeAnalytics($client);

var_dump($analytics->reports->query(
    "channel==MINE",
    '2014-01-01',
    '2014-08-01',
    'views', array(
        'sort' => 'day',
        'dimensions' => 'day'
    )
));
```

#### Getting info for my actual channel id ("channel==UC-CF-1aN7rEN8SBQgT9DDag") - returns 403 error

```
$analytics = new Google_Service_YouTubeAnalytics($client);

var_dump($analytics->reports->query(
    "channel==UC-CF-1aN7rEN8SBQgT9DDag",
    '2014-01-01',
    '2014-08-01',
    'views', array(
        'sort' => 'day',
        'dimensions' => 'day'
    )
));
```

#### Getting info for my channel - this gets a different id to my channel id

```
$service = new Google_Service_YouTube($client);

$channels = $service->channels->listChannels('id,brandingSettings',array(
    'mine' => 'true',
));

var_dump($channels[0]->getId());
```

#### Getting info for aforementioned different channel id - no data

```
var_dump($analytics->reports->query("channel=={$channels[0]->getId()}",...);
```

Checking on youtube for this new channel ID shows "Channel not found".

Any one have any other suggestions? It seems like it must relate to some permissions of the channel? I just don't see what the different id to my channel id is related to.

Comment: did you enable YouTube Data API V3 and YouTube Analytics in your console projects ?

Comment: Yes. I have tried disabling them again to confirm they are enabled ok and I get "(403) Access Not Configured" once they are disabled.

Comment: don't understand this `$channels[0]->getId()`. Should be `$channels["items"][0]["id]` to get the id

Comment: $channels returns a Google_Service_YouTube_ChannelListResponse object. This class has some magic functions so you can read from ["items"] directly by using the object like an array. The problem is not related to that, I have just done it shorthand in the example for readability.

Comment: Are you the owner of the channel? Can you check the same query with API explorer? https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtubeAnalytics/v1/youtubeAnalytics.reports.query

Comment: Yeah, that works. I think its something todo with the authentication method as Im using a p12 key to authenticate my client and maybe this doesn't get full permission of my account on youtube analytics like it does on google analytics?